# Why can't I substitute a value with a variable of the same value in Haskell port numbers?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Here's a GHCI session exhibiting the issue:

```
Prelude> import Network
Prelude Network> PortNumber 1234
PortNumber 1234
Prelude Network> let n = 1234
Prelude Network> PortNumber n

<interactive>:5:12:
    Couldn't match expected type `PortNumber'
                with actual type `Integer'
    In the first argument of `PortNumber', namely `n'
    In the expression: PortNumber n
    In an equation for `it': it = PortNumber n
```

Why doesn't this work? Given a variable stored in an `Integer` (or a `Word16`, I'm reading user input so I can be flexible), why can't I pass it to `PortNumber`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/latest/doc/html/src/Network-Socket-Types.html#PortNumber) says:

```
newtype PortNumber = PortNum Word16 deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable)
-- newtyped to prevent accidental use of sane-looking
-- port numbers that haven't actually been converted to
-- network-byte-order first.
```

In other words, they do not want you messing around with `PortNumber` internals. (Note that there is the `PortNumber`-type and the `PortNumber`-constructor (of the type `PortID`), which is a bit misleading.)

If you want to use an integer variable in `PortNumber` (constructor), you have to convert it to `PortNumber` (type) manually. Fortunately, it is an instance of `Num`, and therefore supports `fromInteger`:

```
Prelude Network> let n = 234
Prelude Network> PortNumber (fromInteger n)
PortNumber 234
```

When you use an integer literal, `fromInteger` gets added automatically by the compiler to make your life easier.

Answer (score 5):

Ghci don't like polymorphic types, if function has no signature, ghci try to made it monomorphic.
But you still can write

```
> let n = 1234 in PortNumber n
```

,

```
> let n = 1234
> PortNumber n

<interactive>:5:12:
```

This happens because ghci help you 1 line earlier, when you add n, `n :not: Num a => a` in gchi, it made it `n :: Integer`. Haskell don't have type conversion. So you also could made type conversion for  `PortNumber Word16`(`Integer -> Word16` using `fromInteger`):

```
>let n = 234
>PortNumber (fromInteger n)
```